# Election results

Tags: discussion

I like to know the results of moderator elections, but only find [this page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election) with 4 images, usually called `flair` in ambigious order - no numbers for each candidate.

Is that all?

Comment: You should probably post this on meta, no?

Comment: Also, looks like the raw voting data is available here: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election/1

Comment: @jozzas: Sorry, I thought I'm on meta. Will delete and restate there. Or better flag it? However, your link only gives me the number of total votes (64) or am I missing something?

Comment: Even as someone who got elected, I have no idea what the break out was.  :)  I think that's a totally behind the scenes type of thing.

Comment: There's a hidden link in that yellow block at the bottom, "election data" in "Download the election data and use OpenSTV for windows or mac to audit the results" is a link. I've got that file open which I believe breaks down the (anonymised) 64 individual votes into their first, second and third choices.

Comment: @Thanks jozzas for the hint with the link. I have problems with some colors - maybe it is better visible for the majority.

Comment: @userunknown Not your fault, the link is completely invisible until you hover over it. It's a UI bug that has popped up a few times since the redesign. That kind of thing should at least be underlined to give users a hint.

Comment: These invisible links keep popping up over and over again. How is it major usability bugs like this keep slipping thorough?

Comment: @YannisRizos yes, I understand that. I've even [made a post myself](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/links-invisible-on-post-notices) already. In fact, [I've made two](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1676/links-in-users-pages-hidden)! My point is the same major usability bug keeps cropping up over and over again in many different places, which is really not acceptable and sloppy. Shows very poor quality control.

Comment: @SamIAm I've made a meta post that consolidates [all of these issues with links](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1787/links-are-styled-identically-to-surrounding-text-many-instances).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSTV reports:

```
Ballot file contains 7 candidates and 64 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 64 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Skeptics Moderator Election 2012 using Meek STV.
7 candidates running for 4 seats.

 R|Fabian            |Sam I Am          |Sklivvz           |Konrad Rudolph    |Larian LeQuella   
  |------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------
  |Alain             |Rory Alsop        |Exhausted         |Surplus           |Threshold         
=================================================================================================
 1|          7.000000|          3.000000|         17.000000|         10.000000|         25.000000
  |          0.000000|          2.000000|          0.000000|         16.399998|         12.800001
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidates Sklivvz and Larian LeQuella have reached the threshold and
  | are elected.
=================================================================================================
 2|         13.724591|          5.566676|         15.372058|         12.928181|         13.432494
  |                  |          2.975998|          0.000002|          4.257324|         12.800000
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Sklivvz, 0.752942 and Larian LeQuella, 0.512001. Candidates Fabian and Konrad
  | Rudolph have reached the threshold and are elected.

Winners are Fabian, Sklivvz, Konrad Rudolph, and Larian LeQuella.
```

A more readable version of that, courtesy of [user unknown](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/24/user-unknown):

```
 R|Fabian   |Sam I Am   |Sklivvz    |Konrad Rudolph |Larian LeQuella   
  |---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------
  |Alain    |Rory Alsop |Exhausted  |Surplus        |Threshold         
====================================================================
 1|     7.00|       3.00|      17.00|         10.000|         25.00
  |     0.00|       2.00|       0.00|         16.399|         12.80
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidates Sklivvz and Larian LeQuella 
  | have reached the threshold and are elected.
====================================================================
 2|    13.72|       5.56|      15.37|         12.928|         13.432
  |         |       2.97|       0.00|          4.257|         12.800
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates 
  | who have exceeded the threshold: Sklivvz, 0.752942 and Larian 
  | LeQuella, 0.512001. Candidates Fabian and Konrad Rudolph have
  | reached the threshold and are elected.
```

Comment: Should have mentioned before, but congratulations to Fabian, Sklivvz, Konrad and Larian!

Comment: Without 6 digits of precision, it would even be readable. :) While the calculation process isn't very obvious. So I accept it, but don't upvote. :)

Comment: I love it how they use [Float instead of Decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/61872) in OpenSTV and get all these absurd approximations.

Comment: Y'll gonna laugh! I already edited it in my editor, and then I realized, that I don' have edit permissions here. :) I can put it into my question, so that you can cut'n'paste it away - would you do that?

Answer (score 4):

Ok. From the file, being advertised as pro Mac and Windows, I extracted:

```
cat skeptics-stackexchange-com-2012-election-results.blt | sed 's/^1 //;s/ 0.$//;s/1/F/;s/2/I/;s/3/S/;s/4/K/;s/5/L/;s/6/A/;s/7/R/' | head -n 65 | tail -n 64 > skeptics
for c in F L S K I R A; do  echo -n $c" "; grep -c $c skeptics; done
F 48
L 45
S 35
K 28
I 24
R 7
A 2
```

That is:

```
48 Fabian
45 Larian LeQuella 
35 Sklivvz
28 Konrad Rudolph
24 sam I am
7 Rory Alsop
2 Alain
```

Gratulations to the winners, and thanks to all candidates from the community - from a minor part of the community. :)

Comment: You'll have to run the election using the STV software to get a more accurate picture, you combined the 1st, 2nd and 3rd vote in your count, as far as I can tell. The number of 1st votes for the candidates differs a lot from this count.